# Cannote create an object, constructor error (for object initialization)

Tags: c++, class, default-constructor

I have created an Stack extension for `std::stack`.

I have created a template class whose code is here:

```
template<class _StackType>
class Stack
{
    std::stack<_StackType> data_container;
    mutable std::mutex M;
public :

    Stack(const Stack& other)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(other.M);
        this->data_container = other.data_container;
    }
```

But when I initialize it :

```
Stack<int> myStack;
```

It throws the following error:

```
 error: no matching function for call to `‘Stack<int>::Stack()’`
```

It seems there is some problems with operator. I did try to create an operator overloading but failed at my attempts.

What is the cause of error?

Comment: There's no operator involved?? You simply missed to specify a default constructor. In case a copy constructor is defined, the compiler won't generate one automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify a default constructor for `Stack`, so the variable `myStack` can't be created.

Normally, the default constructor is implicit, but in your case, because you specified the copy constructor, it is deleted.

Either implement it yourself, or default it explicitly:

```
Stack() = default; // Default implementation of default constructor
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Stack class is missing a default constructor.